# Falha ao tentar atualizar classes e recursos do projeto utilizando Intellij e tomcat

Tags: aplicação-web, tomcat, intellij-idea, resources

Estou usando Intellij para desenvolver um projeto web, o servidor de aplicação utilizado é Tomcat. Configurei teclas de atalho para atualizar os recursos e apenas recarregar a pagina para que as modificações no projeto fossem carregadas.
Estava tudo funcionando, do nada parou. Segue o print das configurações do tomcat no meu projeto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já testei varias opções nos campos 'On update action' e 'On frame deactivation',
não estou obtendo sucesso com nenhuma tentativa.
Como podem ver o artifact selecionado é o exploded conforme recomendado em alguns sites e tutorias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

Na pasta raiz do tomcat abrir a pasta conf;

Abrir o arquivo context.xml;

Dentro do arquivo, no escopo da tag 'context' adicionar a linha:
     Resources cachingAllowed="false"/

Reiniciar a instancia do servidor tomcat dentro do intellij;

Pronto! Todos os arquivos são atualizados ao utilizar Ctrl + F10.
É só carregar a pagina e os arquivos serão atualizados.